# Normalize amplitude and phase with c#

Tags: c#, .net, math, audio, signal-processing

I'm in the situation where i need to do some math related stuff in c# and for that i need some external libarys. The tool i look for should do the following actions:

- Process sound(wave/mp3):

  - Normalize the amplitude
  - Normalize the phase

Any idea which way to go? And is there a big difference if I should to it on mp3 instead of wav

Michael.

Comment: Hi Michael,
When you write "normalize the phase", what do you mean? I assume that "normalize the amplitude" means normalizing the "power" of the audio-signal to say unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and see if [Bass.Net](http://www.un4seen.com/) (comercial) or [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) could work for your purposes.

Comment: I will take a look at the library. Thanks for the help.